# Curly braces not showing value in angular

Tags: angularjs, curly-braces, ng-controller

Following Code is not showing or updating the value of nam in `<p>` tag. Kindly help !

```
<html ng-app>
<head></head>
<body>
<input ng-model = "nam.a" ng-controller = "myControl">
<p> Hello {{nam.a}}  </p>
<script>
function myControl($scope){
$scope.nam =  {
    a : "abcdefg"
};
};
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure that this is angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is no ng-app created, ng-controller is binded in wrong way also. This is the right implementation. Look at the example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myControl">

        <input ng-model="nam.a" >
        <p> Hello {{nam.a}} </p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myControl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.nam = {
                a: "abcdefg"
            };
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes that works. What's wrong with my implementation of ng-controller ?

Comment: Your angular controller declaration is wrong. Look here for examples.http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the app module in html page.

```
 <html ng-app="Test">

<body  ng-controller = "myControl">
<input ng-model = "nam.a"/>
<p> Hello {{nam.a}}  </p>
```

Then inject the module and controller like as below.

```
var app = angular.module('Test', []);
app.controller('myControl', function($scope) {
      $scope.nam =  {
    a : "abcdefg"
};
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you should write like this

```
        <body ng-controller="myControl">
            <input ng-model = "nam.a">
            <p> Hello {{nam.a}}  </p>
         </body>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/M5n5Zb3v3J9W9Mx65cub?p=preview

Comment: You should declared your ng-controller before ur actual code start like i declared in body....Its working know..Why downvote then??

Answer (score -2):

```html
<html>
<body ng-app="yourAppName">
  
  <div  ng-controller="myControl">
    <input ng-model="nam.a">
    <p> Hello {{nam.a}}  </p>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module('yourAppName', [])
      .controller('myControl', function($scope) {
        $scope.nam = {
          a: 'abcdefg'
        }
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- use `angular` to create a module (in the example, I called it `yourAppName`), which you reference in the HTML in the `ng-app` directive
- move the `ng-controller` directive to a parent element for wherever you reference things on `$scope`
- create a controller by using `angular.module(...).controller()` instead of just creating a random JavaScript function